# How to maintain one custom B2B iOS app for multiple clients

Tags: ios, b2b

My company is building one custom B2B app which is quite similar for all clients.

The difference between the apps will be the app's name & icon and perhaps color schema.
Just to be clear - the data in the apps would be different but the layout is identical. e.g. I'd have the same button in all of the apps, but its color maybe be blue in one app and yellow in another.

I was wondering regarding how to maintain this kind of app. 
The apps would be either distributed to app store or to clients' MDMs.

Considering the fact I'm going to have hundreds of apps like this - it's not possible to build & submit each of them for every bug fix I do in the app..

Any solutions out there?

Comment: Why is it not possible to build and submit each of them for every bug fix? If you have one codebase and it is slightly modified for each customer - E.g. custom url or icon , what you could do is maintain custom apps for each customer. This sounds like extra maintenance, and it is. But it can be mostly automated with the proper automated Deployment system like Jenkins or Octopus Deploy. Fighting to keep one version in the app store will probably end up being more or a headache than it's worth. Is there some reason why you can't do this?

Answer (score 1):

If app name and icon has to be different, there is not much you can do - you need a separate binary for each client.

However there is a lot you can do in terms of automating the process, since it looks like most of the codebase is shared between apps. Just to give you an idea - you could have a script which takes some configuration (JSON, XML, etc), Xcode project and then builds and signs apps for each client with correct icon, branding, app name etc.

Essentially you maintain single code base, build tools to provision and distribute the apps and move branding and customisation to a configuration layer.